# Does NASA needs ecologists? If yes, whats the salary of an ecologist?

Tags: nasa

I'm in grade 12 and I'm about to go to Ecology college after this graduation, and I was wondering if nasa needs ecologists or no, and what is the salary for a ecologist.

**Questions:**

1. Does NASA ever send ecologists into space?
2. How much does NASA pays an ecologist?
3. Does NASA sends ecologists in Mars?
4. Does Nasa sends ecologists into ISS? If so, how long do they stay there?

**P.S.** I  need some informations so that I will make some preparations to get hired. The reason I ask, is because I tried to find on internet but I could not find the answer and I was wondering if you could help me a little bit to find the answer. I hope I haven't repeated the question.

Comment: If we are ever going to colonize the moon or Mars, then NASA will need ecologists. However you have to realize that getting into NASA is somewhat like making a major league baseball team. A lot more people would like to do it than there are slots available.

Comment: Nasa hires astrobiologists, which may be tangentially related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look on NASA's website you'll see that the astronauts who go to the ISS have to be trained in multiple sciences, often including ecology and biology, in order to run experiments.

Your question, however, is far too broad - in fact we encourage only one question in a post, because otherwise answers have trouble. I will try and help a bit though:

1) Yes, but only as one of many skills an individual astronaut has. Similarly to people working in the Antarctic - they need to be expert in many disciplines.

2) I don't think this question is relevant - see my answer to 1)

3) Nobody has sent anyone to Mars.

4) See my initial paragraph

Comment: Just askin' in question #2 because we never know when water can discovered in Mars, and I was thinking that NASA also needs ecologists for you know, to be sent on Moon in case something is found or in Mars.

Comment: @AlexA - that makes literally no sense. Why would NASA send an ecologist to the moon because something is found on Mars? Also, if you read my point 1 - no astronaut will have 1 discipline. It's just not worth it. It is so expensive to send someone to space, you need them to be useful.

Comment: Well, maybe ther is ice on Moon and they havent noticed yet? Just sayin'

Comment: @Alex - we know there is ice on the moon. That's not even up for debate. NASA has definitive evidence. But that's not going to get an ecologist going there, and as I said, has nothing to do with Mars